# PHP Mysql select email using MD5 on where clause

Tags: php, mysql

Consider this:

```
$email = 'c5dfd29d956b52c1ffa00ce4a06abad2'; // From the query string (MD5)

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table
          . ' WHERE MD5(email_address) = ' . $email);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['email_address'];
```

I want to get the value from the 'email_column' if the hashed emails are the same (From the database and from the query string using MD5). What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: use another key in your table for authentication instead making email md5

Comment: The provided code looks correct (other than the fact it's using the mysql_* functions which you really shouldn't do.  Use mysqli or pdo instead).

Comment: 1st: return only rows in `SELECT` which are really needed, 2nd: never wrap a column which should be indexed inside a (scalar) function, MySQL wouldn't use the index, 3rd: huh? what's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to add quotes around $email in your query. Also, if you're taking it from the user, never ever forget to do `mysql_real_escape_string` before passing it to the DB.

Also, since MySQL does not allow function indexes, you must understand that this query will require MySQL to read every row of the table and run MD5 on every email to check. You should rather store the hash in a separate field and have an index on it.